# Using querySelectorAll to change the style property of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following function which when triggered will make a DIV become semi-transparent.

```
function changeOpacity(el) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

However I would like this function to apply to several DIVs simultaneously. I tried giving each DIV the same class name and then using `getElementsByClassName` but couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Would `querySelectorAll` be more appropriate and if so how would I implement it?

Comment: **1.** select all matching element using `querySelectorAll` **2.** Loop over this collection and add the styles to individual element. I'd recommend to use class with `classList`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I would select them with a querySelectorAll and loop over them.

```
function changeOpacity(className) {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(className);
    var index = 0, length = elems.length;
    for ( ; index < length; index++) {
        elems[index].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
        elems[index].style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Edit: As a comment said you might be better off putting styling values in a CSS class if they are not dynamic and use:

```
elems[index].classList.add('someclass');
```

Comment: One change -  need to use a comma instead of semi-colon at end of var elems line

Comment: @user2840467 why? its not necessary. and then i would need to use remove the var declaration on next line to make it work.

Comment: Just to simplify it imho. Actually it works as you say but one thing that I've noticed (not against your correct solution but a problem that I didn't address) was that I forgot to add the fullstop to the class names in my function call (slaps head)

Comment: which I didn't post (slaps head again)

Comment: Hey just wondering why are you setting the initialization variables outside of the for statement?

Comment: @the12 are you referring to index and length? For index no reason really, just how I have always done it. As for length, that is for performance reasons. You most likely won't ever see an issue with small lengths but `elems.length` will be called each time it loops when it is inside the for statement and that can affect performance. Better to get the length once outside the loop and store it.

Comment: Ok thanks, and for the loop statement, can you omit the semicolon before `index >length` or is that necessary to show that there aren't going to be any initialization values set in the loop?

Comment: @the12 no problem. Happy to answer and help. The semicolons are required I believe even if you omit the initialization, condition or final expression block. None of the 3 blocks are required but the two semicolons are.

Answer (score 34):

Another way this can be done is with `forEach()` and ES6+

```
function changeOpacity(className) {
    document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(el => {
        el.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
        el.style.opacity = 0.5;
    });
}
```

I especially like this syntax when only one style property needs to be updated. For example, if you only needed to change the opacity, and not the transition, you could use a single line:

```
function setOpacity(className) {
    document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(el => el.style.opacity = 0.5);
}
```

You could then use a separate method for setting the transition:

```
function setTransition(className) {
   document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(
       el => el.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this using Object entries within a FOR-IN:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[attribute name]');

if (elements != undefined) {
    for (let element in Object.entries(elements)) {
        elements[element].style.transition = 'opacity 0.5s linear 0s';
        elements[element].style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Modify for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new ES6 Array.map() to loop over every item and change the properties

```
document.querySelectorAll(selector).map(item => {
item.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
item.style.opacity = 0.5;
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList and not an array. `map` is an array method...

Comment: Yes, this answer will not work. You must convert the `NodeList` to an array first. In modern browsers the easiest way is `Array.from` which works just fine on array-like objects such as `NodeList` . Then you can use map with no issue. `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).map( item => { return item; } );` My only complaint though is you aren't really using `map` properly. `map` returns a new array and expects the provided function to also return a value all of which you ignore here and technically that's an anti-pattern and can lead to all kinds of technical debt among other things.