# Set CSS properties on multiple HTML elements

Tags: javascript

I have this part of a function that sets css properties on two buttons (update, save). I'm trying to minimize the lines of code and i'm looking for a more efficient way of setting css properties on multiple HTML elements rather than writing getElementById for every element. Is querySelectorAll suitable for use in this context?

//Chris

```
var css = {"backgroundColor": "red","textDecoration": "line-through"};
  for (var prop in css) {   
    document.getElementById("update").style[prop] = css[prop];
    document.getElementById("save").style[prop] = css[prop];
  }
```

Comment: There should be a dot after `.style`.

Comment: Yes, querySelectorAll is suitable for use in this context.

Comment: querySelectorAll suitable for use, but to set style you will have to iterate the result of querying and set style for each element in array

Comment: You should look at https://jsperf.com/style-versus-jquery-css/8

Comment: Whoa, jsperf is back again, thanks @shubhamagrawal

Comment: Probably a duplicate question: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178114/using-queryselectorall-to-change-the-style-property-of-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `querySelectorAll` could be used in this context. Be aware that it isn't supported in IE8 or earlier. [Check out the MSN docs for some quirks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

In addition, be aware that `querySelectorAll` returns an array like object (a non live NodeList) so you'll have to modify your code to work with such a structure:

```
var css = {"backgroundColor": "red","textDecoration": "line-through"}; 

var matched = document.querySelectorAll("#update, #save");
matched.forEach(function (c){
  c.style.backgroundColor css.backgroundColor;
  c.style.textDecoration = css.textDecoration;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for an informative answer and also for notyfing the compatibility issues. Luckily only users of IE10 or later will affected by this. I'll try something similar

Comment: Glad you found my answer useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following method

```
var css = {"backgroundColor": "red","textDecoration": "line-through"};
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#update, #save');
for (var prop in css) {
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.style[prop] = css[prop];
    });
}
```

here the `querySelectorAll` is used with multiple selectors

Answer (score 0):

Using document.querySelectorAll you could do it this way.

```
/*declare a css class*/

.button-css{"backgroundColor": "red","textDecoration": "line-through"};

/*in javascript you can do the following*/
var buttons=document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");

buttons.forEach(function(button){
  button.classList.add('button-css');
})
```