# Find element from class-name with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css

I don't really know how I can find an element using `getElementsByClassName()` if the class name is like below.

This is an image on how the CSS look's like on their website and I want to edit the background image using javascript. [CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuTU6.png) When I change the background url directly in the deverloper tool the image change on the website. But it is not working using the javascript nothing is changing.

Website's CSS:

```
.layer.interface-layer .main-column.right-column { 
  background: url(../img/gui/chat-powtarzalny-podklad.png) -251px 0px;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('.layer.interface-layer .main-column.right-column');

panel.style.background = "url(LINK)";
```

Comment: The class-name isn't '*like below*', that's the CSS selector (admittedly formed from the relevant class-names). But given that you - probably - got an error when you attempted to use `getElementsByClassName()` like that - did you look at the documentation at all? Or consider offering us the error message so that we could better help you?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` does not return an "error message". It simply returns nothing when no matching elements were found. Not a particularly helpful or welcoming comment for a new user. https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/.

Comment: @Mike: indeed, but the `panel.style.background` should definitely yield an error. (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vwa50vub/) though, admittedly, the error is related to accessing the `background` property of the non-existent `style` Object of the `panel` collection.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code. According to MDN [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (emphasis mine):

> Returns an **array-like object** of all child elements which have **all of the given class names**.

To begin, this means that you need to index into the object returned:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('.layer.interface-layer .main-column.right-column');
els[0].style.background = "...";
```

However, this still won't work because the elements you are trying to select themselves *only* have class names of `.main-column.right-column`. Their *ancestor* have classes `.layer.interface-layer`.

So what you are looking for is [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). This accepts a CSS selector instead, which is what you seem to be expecting:

```
var panel = document.querySelector('.layer.interface-layer .main-column.right-column');
panel.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/gui/chat-powtarzalny-podklad.png)';
```

Note that if you want update *multiple* elements then you need to instead use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which you can treat like an array. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178161/289319) for how to iterate over the nodes and update each in turn.

The syntax you used `"url(LINK)"` also seems to be wrong. Not sure if this was what you were actually trying or just an example. See above for how to use this properly.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. I was also trying to add > between the class name but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to share enough of your code that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MarchewkaPL this *will* work if you use it correctly. There must be something else you are doing wrong.

Comment: @MarchewkaPL see my edits for further clarification.