# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" on created lifecycle (Vue, buefy)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I'm working on a project using buefy but keep getting hit by the 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` error .

when I try to add class on nested element at `created`() lifecycle. Here are my codes:

```
<code>
    <template>
        <base-messages
          class-name="is-kasmir"
        />
    </template>

    export default {
      created() {
        const element = document.querySelectorAll('.is-kasmir i');
        element.classList.add("mystyle");
      }
    };

</code>
```

Comment: `class-name="is-kasmir"` -> `class="is-kasmir"`

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of elements that doesn't have its own `classList` property. You'll have to iterate/loop through the collection and add the class to each element individually. (Or use `querySelector()` instead if you only want the first matching element.) – Similar example: [Using querySelectorAll to change the style property of multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178114/using-queryselectorall-to-change-the-style-property-of-multiple-elements)

Comment: thank you for the answers, I'll try the solution offered!