# Access nesting elements

Tags: javascript

I use multiple buttons with a common class. When the user clicks on any of the buttons, I want to make elements with another class fill in red.

So basically I want to color everything inside `.wrapper` that has the `.col` class.

This is what I have so far.

```
var clickMe = document.querySelectorAll('.common');
for (var i = 0; i < clickMe.length; i++) {
  clickMe[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    var x = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper svg .col'); //this is where my issue starts.
    x.style.fill = "red";

  }, false);
}
```

Looking for a pure javascript solution.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper svg .col') returns an array, so you need to traverse the array and set style for individual elements like document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper svg .col') [i]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using querySelectorAll to change the style property of multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178114/using-queryselectorall-to-change-the-style-property-of-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like following should work for you:

```
var clickMe = document.querySelectorAll('.common');
for (var i = 0; i < clickMe.length; i++) {
  clickMe[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    var x = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper svg .col'); //this is where my issue starts.
    for(var j=0;j<x.length;j++){
      x[j].style.fill = "red";
    }


  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Not a problem :) Also, please don't forget to upvote to verify the solution and help others :)