# Using document.querySelector('.').style. to change *two* CSS properties of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to set up a truncated textbox that expands to fullsize with a click/tap on the textbox. My div `.textbox` has `height:10em`, `overflow:hidden`, and there's a "there is more..." fade-out effect over the bottom third of the textbox using `.textbox:after {height: 3em; background: linear-gradient}` ([found here](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) - see Fade Out Way). Found on SO a script for expanding `.textbox` to `height:auto`.

```
<script>
document.querySelector('.textbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.textbox').style.height='auto';
});
</script>
```

Problem is, the `.textbox:after` fade-out effect still covers the bottom 3em of the expanded textbox, obscuring the text. So, on click/tap, I need the script to change the padding-bottom of `.textbox` from 0 to 3em (as well as increase height to auto). 
Can the script above handle those two changes? I've searched and only find examples for changing a single property, like color or  border ([e.g. here](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-style-dom/)) or using javascript to [change multiple divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178114/using-queryselectorall-to-change-the-style-property-of-multiple-elements). I've tinkered, but the results are either the script doesn't work or it only effects height: auto.

**Oops!**
Sorry, Little bug found in my setup when applying the answer. I also have a "Close" button within the textbox and if I click that, the textbox expands for a flash before closing. Tried giving the "Close" button a huge z-index, but no luck. So I need to move the queryselector from the entire textbox to the first paragraph (p class="expand") of text. So I guess I'd start with...

```
document.querySelector('.expand').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.textbox').style.height='auto';
```

...but the `this.style.paddingBottom='2em';` has no effect. What do I do?

**Final note.** [Two solutions here....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689908/using-document-queryselector-style-to-change-two-css-properties-of-a-dif)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just set the other property as well. The changes don't take effect until the browser re-renders anyway (after your JavaScript event handler has returned);

```
document.querySelector('.textbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.height='auto';
  this.style.paddingBottom='3em';
});
```

Notice that you can use `this` to refer to the element within the handler, no need to go find it again.

---

**However**, I would recommend defining a class for this and then adding/removing it as necessary, rather than using direct style properties.

Comment: Sorry, answer correct but new problem created (my fault). Please see post.

Comment: @plugincontainer - You'll want to post that as a new question, since it's a new question. Be sure to include a [mcve] in it, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: The question is still about "Using document.querySelector('.').style. to change *two* CSS properties of a div". The only change I made is the document.querySelector is now ('.expand'), not ('.textbox'). So, if you can give me the full syntax for changing *two* CSS properties of the .textbox div -- without the use of "this" (I'm assuming it's an optional shortcut since you wrote "you can use this to refer to the element within the handler, no need to go find it again" -- would I have the answer to the original question (and the new question)?

Comment: @plugincontainer - No, you wouldn't. The flicker you're talking about is a completely different issue than this question. (If for some reason you don't want to use `this`, you would just save the element reference in a variable: `var el = document.querySelector(".textbox"); el.style.height = ...; el.style.paddingBottom = ...;` But beware that if you change your page, adding or removing a `.textbox` element, you may select a different one when the handler runs. Which is a reason to use `this`.)

Comment: For me the flicker was never an issue - I want to work around it by using the first para of the textbox - rather than the entire textbox - as the place to click. The first para is out of range of the close button. My knowledge of javascript syntax is limited, so if you can spell out (with an edit to your answer) the full syntax for the answer I'd appreciate it. Appreciate cos it'll save me lots of time spent looking into el =

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<script>
const textbox = document.querySelector('.textbox');
textbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textbox.style.height = 'auto';
  textbox.style.paddingBottom ='3em';
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel, your answer works too, but my question is superseded by problems with the textbox "close" button (see changes to question)