# Using document.querySelector('.').style. to change *two* CSS properties of a different div

Tags: javascript, html, css

In follow-up to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686764/using-document-queryselector-style-to-change-two-css-properties-of-a-div). I have the following script:

```
 document.querySelector('.clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.style.color = '#f00';
     this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
 });
```

...which means when the div `.clickme` is clicked/tapped, the script changes `.clickme`'s own `color` and `backgroundColor` properties. Now, instead, I need the script to change not `.clickme's` own properties, but the `color` and `backgroundColor` of another element on the page, a div class (let's call it) `.zebra`. How should the script be modified to achieve that? (The target of the click/tap would still be `.clickme`.)

Comment: Locate the other element with another call to `document.querySelector()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the other element with `document.querySelector(".zebra")` and change its color and background color:

```
document.querySelector('.clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let zebra = document.querySelector('.zebra')
    zebra.style.color = '#f00';
    zebra.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
});
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.querySelector('.zebra')` inside click event handler

```
document.querySelector('.clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.style.color = '#f00';
     this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
     document.querySelector('.zebra').style.color = 'blue';
     document.querySelector('.zebra').style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
 });
```

```js
document.querySelector('.clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.style.color = '#f00';
     this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
     document.querySelector('.zebra').style.color = 'blue';
     document.querySelector('.zebra').style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
 });
```

```html
<div class='clickme'>Click me</div>
<div class='zebra'>Zebra</div>
```