# How to get one script to change Z-Index on two boxes?

Tags: javascript, button, z-index

This is my first website project; I want the one `<button>` to change the `z-index` on two boxes. Two buttons would be no problem, but I want the script to do two things in one action. I couldn´t find any information about this subject online.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("DIV1").style.zIndex = "-1";
}
```

```css
#DIV1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#DIV2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<div id="DIV1">
  <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
</div>

<div id="DIV2">
  <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You know that you can execute more than one single statement in a function, no? Select `document.getElementById("DIV1").style.zIndex = "-1";`, copy it, paste it below the existing one, and modify it accordingly ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DarkBee: it isn't, necessarily, though it can sometimes lead to more gentle answers/comments. I didn't edit it out because I didn't really consider it an issue, though, then there was a flurry of editing and apparently I just didn't verify the previous edit.

Comment: The most simple toggle approach was to group the two elements as children of a single parent element. This element then features a class name which will be toggled via `elmNode.classList.toggle`. With this element's class name one provides an additional rule which will prefer one child element over the other whereas the default is the natural layering of the child elements.

Comment: @HenrikF ... Since there are two answers which each indicate a different understanding/perception of the OP's problem ... does the OP want to toggle the layers on button-click, or does the OP want both element's z-indices to be set each to `-1`?

Comment: @HenrikF ... is the OP still participating in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  ['DIV1', 'DIV2'].map(elementId => {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.classList.add('class');
  });
}
```

```css
#DIV1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#DIV2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.class {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<div id="DIV1">
  <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
</div>
<div id="DIV2">
  <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: **One does not use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** (which creates a new array with a mapped value for each item of the processed array) **when one wants to execute code [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array item** (clear indication for it ... no return value other then the `undefined` default for the callback function) **.**

Comment: Map does not work in all browsers (IE specifically), I would avoid this unless you are using a compiler such as web-pack to convert es6.

Comment: Thankyou every one for every answer. I was looking for one answer and got a better "toggle".

Comment: @HenrikF ... You're welcome; the OP nevertheless is encouraged to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer which was most helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple **toggle approach** was to group the two elements as children of a single parent-element. This element then features an additional class-name which will be toggled via [`parentNode.classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle). With this parent-element's toggle-specific class-name one provides an additional rule which will prefer one child element over the other, whereas the default is the natural layering of the child elements.

```js
function toggleLayers() {
  document
    .querySelector('.toggle-box')
    .classList
    .toggle('toggle-on');
}
document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', toggleLayers);
```

```css
.toggle-box {
  position: relative;
}
.toggle-box > :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.toggle-box > :last-child {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.toggle-box.toggle-on > :last-child {
  z-index: -1;
}
button { margin-bottom: 5px; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<button>toggle layers</button>

<div class="toggle-box">
  <div>
    <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your elements and select by class instead. As mentioned here
[Using querySelectorAll to change the style property of multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178114/using-queryselectorall-to-change-the-style-property-of-multiple-elements)

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<div class="heading" id="DIV1">
  <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
</div>

<div class="heading" id="DIV2">
  <h1>Gone fishing</h1>
</div>
```

```
function myFunction() {

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.heading');
    var index = 0, length = elems.length;
    for ( ; index < length; index++) {
        elems[index].style.zIndex = "-1";
    }
}
```